# bulma level class not going to right side

Tags: bulma

I'm trying to use a `level` inside of a `panel` with Bulma but the `level-right` seems to be completely ignored.  I'm just getting all the text squished together on the left side.  this is what I tried.

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="panel">
        <p class="panel-heading">Points For Order</p>
    </div>
    <p class="panel-tabs">
        <a class="is-active">Order</a>
        <a>Completed</a>
    </p>
    <div class="panel-block">
        <div class="level">
            <div class="level-left">
                <div class="level-item">
                    <p class="subtitle is-5">
                        <strong>bmsw</strong>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="level-right">
                <p style="text-align: right" class='level-item'>12</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have a bunch more `panel-block` items like that.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to a Bulma bug.

Workaround is to add `display: block` to the `.panel-block` class

See: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1563#issuecomment-354723684